# LibGDX FileHandle: Renaming a file deletes the file

Tags: java, libgdx

To rename a file I use

`FileHandle#moveTo(FileHandle dest)`

It works fine in most cases. But when I try to rename, for example, a file "abc" to "ABC", the file gets deleted.
I think the problem is that file names are insensitve ( at least on Desktop, Windows). 
This is the implementation of the method mentioned above (I left commentaries in the code):

```
public void moveTo (FileHandle dest) {
    if (type == FileType.Classpath) throw new GdxRuntimeException("Cannot move a classpath file: " + file);
    if (type == FileType.Internal) throw new GdxRuntimeException("Cannot move an internal file: " + file);
    copyTo(dest); // file is not copied into another file, since "abc" file  is the same as the dest "ABC" file
    delete(); // and here the "original" file is deleted, but in this case original file equals to dest file, so the file is lost
    if (exists() && isDirectory()) deleteDirectory();
}
```

Questions:

1) Is such behaviour intentional? Honestly, it feels wrong.

2) Is it ok to do renaming like this (it works in this case, but maybe there are another caveats):

```
FileHandle src = ...;
FileHandle dest = ...;
src.file().renameTo(dest.file());
```

If not, what's the right way?

**Update**

As @exenza suggested, opened an [issue](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues/5019) on LibGDX issue tracker

Comment: What OS does your desktop app work on? Android or linux the `moveTo` method should work fine, as "abc" != "ABC". Windows is case insensitive to the file names, afaik

Comment: The Desktop OS is Windows, forgot to mention. And yes, there is no problem on Android. But still doesn't feel right, shouldn't such method have expected behavior on any platform?

Comment: I agree, in my opinion, the behavior should be the same across all supported by LibGDX operating systems. At least it shouldn't be deleting the file on Windows, imho. I'd recommend to raise a question/bug [on LibGDX issue tracker](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/issues). If you do, please post the reference here

Answer (score 2):

On Windows, file names are case insensitive. This means that "abc" and "ABC" refer to the same file. Your `copyTo()` call, will copy the file to itself. Then `delete()` deletes the file. During all of this there is only one file and no copy.

Comment: Thank you for confirming my assumptions. Is there a convenient solution for the problem?

Comment: @Arctic45 Why do you need to rename the file in the first place? Does libGDX have a `moveTo()` function so that you do not have to do the manual delete?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what do you mean. I don't manually delete files. There is only one `moveTo()` method in `FileHandle`, and in my question I put its original implementation, I did not write that code. And there is no `rename` method, so I use `moveTo` instead.

Comment: @Arctic45 I misread your question and thought that you wrote the code posted in your OP

Comment: @Arctic45 I suggest that you file a big report with libgdx